# TypeScript, VSCode: keyof type not working as expected when switching to insider version of vscode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I recently switched from VSCode to VSCode - Insiders (basically a nightly build) due to performance issues and for some reason I'm getting a new linting error in my code. I'm using TypeScript version 3.5.1

The following is a simplified example:

```
  private updateTransaction = (
    k: 'description' | 'amount' | 'timestamp' | 'vendorId',
    v: ITransaction['description' | 'amount' | 'timestamp' | 'vendorId']
  ) => {
    if(this.state.selectedTransaction){
      this.state.selectedTransaction[k] = v;
    }
  };
```

where `ITransaction` is:

```
export interface ITransaction {
  description: string;
  amount: number;
  timestamp: string;
  vendorId: number;
}
```

Before I switched to the Insider build, this was not an error but if I open the identical project in the Insider version of VSCode TypeScript complains that:

> Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string & number'.
>
> > Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & number'.
> >
> > > Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here? I'm not sure if this is a bug in VSCode insiders build or if my typing is incorrect and this error message genuinely makes no sense to me. I use the pattern `type KeyType = keyof Interface` and `Interface[KeyType]` frequently and I've never seen this error message before.

[I rebuilt a close approximation in the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20ITransaction%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20description%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20amount%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20timestamp%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20vendorId%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TransactionKey%20%3D%20'description'%20%7C%20'amount'%20%7C%20'timestamp'%20%7C%20'vendorId'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20TestState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20selectedTransaction%3F%3A%20ITransaction%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20testState%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20selectedTransaction%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20description%3A%20'string'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20amount%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20timestamp%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20vendorId%3A%201%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20updateTransaction(k%3A%20TransactionKey%2C%20v%3A%20ITransaction%5BTransactionKey%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(testState.selectedTransaction)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20testState.selectedTransaction%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20v%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) but the error no longer occurs. If I copy and paste that into VSCode though, I see the same error as above. I'm thinking that means I should make this a github issue but I'm afraid I'm missing something obvious

Comment: Does this code constitute a [mcve]?  I can't tell if I should just not try to answer because the question strongly depends on projects and types I don't have (immerjs, `Draft`, `TransactionActivity`, etc), or if those are not really relevant to your issue.  If it's the former, please tag the question with all required dependencies. If it's the latter, please provide enough type information for someone to drop the code into some IDE (ideally you would provide a link to a web IDE already configured with the issue).  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I restructured my question and included an example, though the error does not occur in the TS playground

Comment: @jcalz definitely agree the question could be better but we all know what breaking change this probably is https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yeah, I didn’t make that connection when I read the question for some reason... too distracted by all the errors in my IDE when I started looking at the code.  Feel free to answer this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the insider version of vs code, you are probably using typescript 3.5. This release has a [breaking change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types).

The basic idea is that until now typescript allowed write operations to `obj[k] = v` where `k: keyof typeof obj` if `v` was a union of possible values in `obj`:

```
let o = { nr: 0, str: "" }
declare let k: keyof typeof o;
o[k] = 0
o[k] = ""
```

This was unsound. The example above works in 3.4 and below, but if `k` is `'nr'` then the second assignment put `o` in an invalid state. If `k` is `'str'` then the first assignment puts the object in an invalid state.

The simple solution is to use a type assertion:

```
function updateTransaction(k: TransactionKey, v: ITransaction[TransactionKey]) {
    if (testState.selectedTransaction) {
        testState.selectedTransaction[k] = v as any;
    }
}
```

This is still unsound, but not more so than before.

Comment: And the sound version of that code would be to use a generic `K extends TransactionKey`, right?

Comment: @jcalz you'd think so at first glance but no. `K` could be a union so you get back to the same issue.. The workaround in the docs handles only numbers.. I don't think there is way to get it type safe and have the same functionality.

Comment: Ugh.  That's quite unpleasant.

Comment: @jcalz if you finda type safe version, I will bow out of this answer and defer to you. I really think this new check should have been under a new strict flag, seems to be causing a lot of grief. Biggest breaking change I can remember. Oh well hindsight is 20 /20

Comment: So it's [this pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769), and it makes something like [this suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) (or [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25879) more needed.  We want to be able to specify that `K` is a unit type and therefore acts like a union and not an intersection on property writes.

Comment: @jcalz Yup! The `oneof` suggestion would work. Although I see the reticence to add a new type of constraint, I feel we are anyway fast approaching a point where the TS type system is too complicated for an average user to keep up with. Sure it's fun for you and me, but the average programmer does not have time for this.

Comment: @jcalz um .. wierd .. so the answer is to just type the `testState` variable and it will work as before?! Uh ... I did read that did not think how it applied to this case ..

Comment: look at [this](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUpxAZ0WYAexGQG8AoZZAEwhwSmAAcDiB+ALmRzEZAHMA3JWRwAtoQCu4TshCSxAI2jCqBMXTDimsnnyEiAbhBDVCUVNVnylK8gF9yYAJ5MUmbHgSsQAaQjOyAC8yADWAYQwaB64+EQgwqCQsIjumgDKWpBkIjgQADYQ3hDUMV4+shhYsd7xwo4A9A1yECXIYISiICCEWShwOMjoGX3IABbQEAA0yL0TUADuwHnIwGDIS-n5yIpw+aGi60yEODjAivmBA2f8IKD8yNK0MKBt+XDJMwOr6wvfIHAoFBCAsSuQEMQeO0Rh8IFxhjxMrDgjkqHlCsVStVyvEuBQqFRaPRGCxccgAER6e7kqYiKjiKTgLgARlpBPawA0PG0XHJNLpyGMpnMlhZIkc9mEMGktWIjyY1FhZTixAAPL5kBAAB6QUyDZWyvwBAB8AApQlxfDNDFwqp4VSAANq+AC6AEpUasoqbIIi+gA6dFFSBY+2Gj34gm+sBIyCBgrBkoGnyO0IulGGVTICXkIA)

Comment: I think it's just `testState` was narrowed to not allow `undefined` subproperties

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, that was what I also discovered after your initial comment with code ..

Comment: @jcalz I don't think it's about the undefined, I think your initial comment about the 'something nominal' is correct. If I assert to `string | undefined` and `number | undefined` I still get the same issue ..

Comment: @jcalz I will just delete my answer then .. slinking away .. :)

Comment: @jcalz Hm .. I can't delete the accepted answer .. maybe after you post yours I can ..

Comment: I don't have enough confidence in what's going on to try to take over this answer.  Feel free to put the generic solution at the end of your answer.